# Initial guess in Newton-Raphson method.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, functional-equations, newton-raphson, legendre-polynomials

To find roots using the Newton-Raphson method, the initial guess is very important otherwise it may take several iterations to give the value of roots. For the given Legendre polynomial ($ P _ 8 $), what should be the starting point?
$$ P _ 8 ( x ) = \frac { 6435 x ^ 8 - 12012 x ^ 6 + 6930 x ^ 4 - 1260 x ^ 2 + 35 } { 128 } $$

**My Attempt:** For polynomials, the initial guess doesn't matter but if explicitly asked to make a good guess we will be required to plot the curve (plot attached) once but that defeats the purpose of finding solutions using NR method.

Kindly suggest if there is an alternative approach for this problem.

[image: Curve]

Comment: It´s even worse. The 8-th degree polynomial has 8 roots, probably 8 real roots. With the NR method you will get one this roots, depending on where you start. From your plot it is hard to guess an appropriate initial value.

Comment: The initial guess absolutely **does** matter for polynomials. Try messing around with the initial guess in this [Desmos demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y6x8pi7kzq). Notice how the initial guess's location affects which root it goes towards.

Comment: In fact, as $P_8$ has multiple roots ([demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ghfskrzu9y)), the question is somewhat ill-framed. What is the goal? To achieve any root's approximation? A particular one? Is there a particular stopping criterion (a desired level of accuracy or number of iterations)? The only answer I think you could reasonably get otherwise is "anything not too close to a zero of $P_8'$" since Newton's method is ill-behaved near those points, and even that is incredibly vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very lucky with this problem since Francesco Tricomi gave a very nice asymptotic approximation of the zero's of Legendre polynomials.

Letting $x_{n,k}$ be the $k^{\text{th}}$ root of $P_n(x)$, ordered in decreasing order, they are given by

$$x_{n,k}\sim\left(1-\frac{1}{8 n^2}+\frac{1}{8 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)\cos\left(\frac{4k-1}{4n+2}\pi\right)$$

For the case of $P_8(x)$, the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & +0.960182 &  +0.960290 \\
 2 & +0.796653 &  +0.796666 \\
 3 & +0.525532 &  +0.525532 \\
 4 & +0.183435 &  +0.183435 \\
 5 & -0.183435 &  -0.183435 \\
 6 & -0.525532 &  -0.525532 \\
 7 & -0.796653 &  -0.796666 \\
 8 & -0.960182 &  -0.960290
\end{array}
\right)$$

With such estimates, Newton method will converge very fast.